# Constructing n-ary tree from different types of classes c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have two different classes as shown below.

```
Class2{

public:
 Class2();

private:
  int a;

}

Class1{
  public:
       Class1();   
  private:
       Class2 foo;
}
```

Now I want to construct a tree whose some nodes are Class1 and some others are Class2. Is it possible ?

**EDIT**

Class1 will be always child of Class2 or vice versa

Comment: "Class1 will be always child of Class2 or vice versa". Just make a tree of the parent type?

Comment: How would you access the nodes? You cannot say `node->a` or `node->foo` because you don't know what type `node` is. A possible answer is saving a tag that says what type it is. Another is to use virtual functions. Another is to just use two different trees and yet another to always store both. There is no generic answer, the decision depends on the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: There's no parent/child relationship evident in the code you posted. You have two independent classes, one of which has a member if type Class2. I think you should probably learn more C++ before you try to do this.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly. `Class1` and `Class2` are unrelated types (one is not inherited from the other and they are not inherited from the same base class). You want to build a tree with nodes holding a `Class1` instance in the odd-numbered levels and a `Class2` instance in the even-numbered levels. Correct? If so, you could use a templated node/tree class.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider using a [typed-union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)?

E.g.

```
const int TYPE_CLASS1 = 1;
const int TYPE_CLASS2 = 2;

struct Node {
    int type;
    union obj {
        Class1 c1;
        Class2 c2;
    }
};
```

Comment: I need to store them as an hierarchical order

Comment: @eday Right so then just add fields to the node as you would to a normal node in a tree.